I get a Seg Fault when releasing COM object (WICImagingFactory)
I've begun creating a simple game engine using Direct2D, but I've encountered an issue of getting a seg fault whenever I release the IWICImagingFactory*. The issue only occurs when the program is closed.
Minimal Reproducible Sample:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

template <class Interface>
void SafeRelease(
    Interface *&pInterfaceToRelease)
{
    if (pInterfaceToRelease != nullptr)
    {
        pInterfaceToRelease->Release();
        pInterfaceToRelease = nullptr;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register Window Class
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Class Name";
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create and Show Window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Class Name", L"Test Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                               CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                               NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // Create d2d factory and render target
    ID2D1Factory *pD2DFactory;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *pRT;
    D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pD2DFactory);
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd, D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top)),
        &pRT);

    // Create Imaging Factory
    IWICImagingFactory *pWICFactory;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pWICFactory));

    // Start loop
    bool windowOpen = true;
    MSG msg;
    while (windowOpen)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            SafeRelease(pWICFactory);
            SafeRelease(pRT);
            SafeRelease(pD2DFactory);
            UnregisterClass(L"Class Name", hInst);
            CoUninitialize();
            windowOpen = false;
            break;
        }

        pRT->BeginDraw();
        pRT->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::CornflowerBlue));
        pRT->EndDraw();
    }

    return 0;
}

I'm compiling the program using gcc:
g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g test.cpp -municode -mwindows -ld2d1 -lole32 -lwindowscodecs -o test.exe

I've tried eliminated any use of the IWICImagingFactory* beyond creating it by not loading any images, but the issue persists. Images still load fine. I also ensured that the pointer isn't null before calling Release().

Instead of writing your own code for refount managment use ATL::CComPtr (and other ATL support classes). CoInitializeEx/CoUnitialize should be done in main (or at the start of a thread). Also make sure you released ALL com objects before calling CoUnitialize

Use a debugger to determine which part of the Release is failing. (1) pWICFactory is null; (2) pWICFactory is not null, but not a valid pointer, (3) pWICFactory is a valid pointer, but the vtable is invalid, (4) pWICFactory is a valid pointer, the vtable is valid, but the function pointer in the vtable is invalid, (5) pWICFactory is a valid pointer, the vtable is valid, the function pointer in the vtable is valid, and we are running the WIC factory's destructor, and we crash in the destructor.

@RaymondChen When I used a debugger, I found that the pointer is not null, but when stepping through the code, I get a segfault as soon as SafeRelease() is called. I've edited the original question to include a minimal sample of when the error occurs.

A lot is happening inside SafeRelease. Which of the 5 things I listed above is the one that is going wrong?

Your program never calls CoInitialize. You have to do that before calling CoCreateInstance. (And also you can't call CoUninitialize unless you have already done a successful CoInitialize.) You never checked the result of CoCreateInstance - it probably failed.

Thank you to everyone who replied. The issue with the code sample I provided was that it didn't call CoInitialize(), which I forgot to include. The issue with my program itself was that there was an object that held a ID2D1Bitmap* that was created with the IWICImagingFactory and stored in static memory. The problem was that the bitmap was being released after the IWICImagingFactory, which caused a seg fault.

Releasing after the IWICImagingFactory is fine. What is not fine is releasing after CoUninitialize.
